# Runs for the first iteration and fails in the second

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, turtle-graphics

This particular code of mine, runs for the first iteration, however, as it continues it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test1.py", line 7, in <module>

    if len((hex(s)[2:])) == 1:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The code is as follows:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

s = 0

z = 30

for i in range(s,16777217):[enter image description here][1]

    if len((hex(s)[2:])) == 1:

        hex = '#' + '00000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()

    elif len((hex(s)[2:])) == 2:

        hex = '#' + '0000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()

    elif len((hex(s)[2:])) == 3:

        hex = '#' + '000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()

    elif len((hex(s)[2:])) == 4:

        hex = '#' + '00' + hex(s)[2:].upper()

    elif len((hex(s)[2:])) == 5:

        hex = '#' + '0' + hex(s)[2:].upper()

    else:

        hex = '#' + hex(s)[2:].upper()

    t.color(hex)

    t.circle(z)

    s += 1

    z += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first iteration, `hex` refers to a built-in function that makes hexacecimal representations of numbers. But then this line runs...

```
hex = '#' + '00000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()
```

And forever afterwards, `hex` no longer refers to a function, but instead points to a string starting with "#00000". You can't call a string, so attempting to do `hex(...)` in the second iteration causes a crash.

To avoid this naming collision, change the name of your `hex` variable to something else.

```
hex_val = '#' + '00000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()
#or
s = '#' + '00000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()
#or
Kevin = '#' + '00000' + hex(s)[2:].upper()
```

... Or whatever else you prefer; anything but `hex`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `hex` vs. `hex()` issue that @Kevin nicely points out (+1), I don't believe your code will achieve it's goal for several reasons:

Your end target should be 16777216, not 16777217 as that value - 1 doesn't fit into a 6 digit hex string; your circle is askew relative to the origin; your window isn't large enough for the number of colors you generate -- you need a step in your `for` loop that's significantly larger than 1; your code will take a very long time to complete and will mostly be drawing off screen during that time.

Below is my rework of your code addressing the above issues:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SIZE = 1000
LIMIT = 2 ** 24
INCREMENT = int(LIMIT / (2 ** 0.5 * SIZE / 2))  # fill to corners

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SIZE, SIZE)
screen.tracer(0)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed('fastest')

for radius, n in enumerate(range(0, LIMIT, INCREMENT)):

    my_hex = '#' + format(n, "06X")

    yertle.color(my_hex)

    yertle.penup()
    yertle.sety(yertle.ycor() - 1)
    yertle.pendown()

    yertle.circle(radius)
    screen.update()  # only show completed circles

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

If we want to maximize colors on a typical screen, we switch to a 1024 x 1024 window; allocate the 10 bits of color unevenly but always as the highest bits in the color values; only draw one quadrant of the circle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SIZE = 2 ** 10
MASK_3 = 2 ** 3 - 1  # divide our 10 bits into three uneven
MASK_4 = 2 ** 4 - 1  # groups of r=3, g=3, b=4

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SIZE + 8, SIZE + 8)  # rough adjustment for borders
screen.tracer(0)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed('fastest')

yertle.penup()
yertle.goto(-SIZE // 2, -SIZE // 2)  # center of circle is LL corner of window
yertle.pendown()

for radius in range(SIZE):

    my_hex = "#{:01X}0{:01X}0{:01X}0".format(2 * ((radius // 2 ** 7) & MASK_3), 2 * ((radius // 2 ** 4) & MASK_3), radius & MASK_4)

    yertle.color(my_hex)

    yertle.penup()
    yertle.sety(yertle.ycor() - 1)
    yertle.pendown()

    yertle.circle(radius)
    screen.update()  # only show completed arcs

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

We're still only showing 10 bits of the 24 bit color range.